# Error "Reconstruction failed" with soul package

Tags: macros, errors, soul

I've got a problem with the soul package while adding a letter-spacing to a result of a command that is defined just like this:

```
\newcommand{\myCommand}{some text}
```

In the document I'd like to have the result of that command displayed with letter-spacing:

```
\par{\centering{\Huge
 \textbf{\myAnotherCommand{} \textsc{\so{\myCommand{}}}}
}\bigskip\par}
```

but I get "Package soul error: Reconstruction failed" and a black square after the text "some text". If I understand soul package documentation properly, it's a problem with "grouping hyphenatable material" or font switching commands, isn't it? Unfortunately, I've no idea how to fix it. Am I supposed to register some command with \soulregister?

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With pdflatex the most easy way to get letterspacing is via **microtype**

```
\usepackage{microtype}

...

\par
{\centering\Huge
 \textbf{\myAnotherCommand{} \textsc{\lsstyle \myCommand}}
 \par\bigskip}
```

This avoids the need to do all the involved tricks of **soul**. Letterspacing can be obtained via the package **letterspace** (included with **microtype**), but it doesn't hurt to load the bigger one (it's very advantageous, actually).

With XeLaTeX a similar effect can be obtained with

```
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2.0}
```

(the number can be chosen to suit one's needs):

```
\par
{\centering\Huge
 \textbf{\myAnotherCommand{} \textsc{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2.0} \myCommand}}
 \par\bigskip}
```

This particular combination might fail, because not all fonts family have a boldface small caps font.

Comment: Thanks for showing me another way to do that. It's really much simpler and works fine for me :)