# Soul package and spacing problems

Tags: spacing, soul

Similar problems with `soul` package can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23018/14757) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160220/14757). But since my problem is simpler than those (even related with spacing) I guess that it could have a simpler solution.

The problem occurs using underlined text `\ul{}` containing spacing corrections `.\`.

**Here is the MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{soulutf8}    

\begin{document}
Regular text. 

\ul{Underlined text.} 

Regular text. 

\ul{Underlined text with abbreviated word, for example L. Euler}. 

Regular text. 

\ul{Underlined text with abbreviated word and spacing corrections using \texttt{dot backslash}, for example L.\ Euler}

\end{document}
```

**The result is**

[image]

Comment: (not tested) i think that if you can separate the dot from the backslash in the input in such a way that latex still recognizes that the last period is punctuation, you'll get the proper spacing without losing the following word.  try inserting braces there: `.{}\ `

Comment: @barbarabeeton, it still does not work.

Comment: i've just performed some experiments that demonstrate that `soul` does *not* apply end-of-sentence spacing after abbreviations.  or even, for that matter, at the end of sentences.  (i'll have to check the documentation to see if that's mentioned.)  if you'd like me to show the test in an answer, let me know, otherwise this comment will suffice.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for your effort to understand the problem and maybe find a solution. Don't worry, you don't need to show the tests. I'll just follow the comments here. For a while I'm not using spacing corrections. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sigur: Use either `L.{} Euler` or `L.~Euler`.

Comment: @Werner, is the result the same? Or is it almost similar?

Comment: After an uppercase letter, TeX does not think that the abbreviation dot is a period ater a sentence with prolonged space. `L. Euler` is sufficient here.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek -- true, and relevant here, but i've pretty well demonstrated (to my own satisfaction) that `soul` does not observe the prolonged space even *at* the end of a sentence.  i intend to explore this more fully when i have more time on the weekend.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, nice! I didn't know about it. Is it the same with two letters (e.g. `Ap.\ Foo`)?

Comment: @Sigur: [It's equivalent](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L91o1.png), except that `~` inserts a non-breaking space (or tie), keeping `L.` together with `Euler`.

Comment: @Sigur: No, the letter before the dot is lowercase.