# Line-width distributed letter-spacing with \newcommand macros

Tags: macros, microtype, soul, letterspacing

I am using the `soul` package to produce "distributed" text. That is, text that is automatically spaced such that it fills the entire line. This works great, but now what I want to do is use a `\newcommand` within this context, so I can remove redundancy from my source files.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\distribute{}{0pt plus 1fil}{0pt plus 2fil}{0pt}

\newcommand{\greeting}{Hello, World!}

\begin{document}
  \distribute{\greeting}
\end{document}
```

If you replace `\greeting` in `\distribute` with literal text, then it works fine. However, with `\greeting` it results in a "Reconstruction failed" error. The `soul` documentation says this is due to "grouping hyphenable material" or "leaking font switches". The former can be resolved with an `\mbox`, but then that prevents the letter-spacing from happening; the latter doesn't mean much to me, but I don't think it applies here.

Is there a way of getting line-width distributed letter-spacing containing variables?

---

A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23018/error-reconstruction-failed-with-soul-package) is answered with, "Use `microtype`." This package, however, looks pretty low-level and I'm not sure where to begin to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the expl3 construct `\exp_args`, which expands arguments before a macro is executed. See [Expanding arguments before macro call](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104506/expanding-arguments-before-macro-call) for example.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}
\sodef\distribute{}{0pt plus 1fil}{0pt plus 2fil}{0pt}

\newcommand{\greeting}{Hello, World!}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\expdistribute}{m}{%
\exp_args:No\distribute{#1}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\expdistribute{\greeting}

\distribute{Hello, World!}

\distribute{All your base are belong to us}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- this works in my minimal example, but it doesn't seem to work in my actual document, which is a bit more complicated... Never mind; I can live with redundancy :)